# I want to know the last login time and date of users on OBIEE 11g. How do I do that?

Tags: oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I have 41 users in OBIEE 11g. I wish to track the last login/logout date and time of all these users. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by capturing and analysing the Presentation Services log file for HTTP events. 
Concepts are detailed in this article: 
http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/11/auditing-obiee-presentation-catalog-activity-with-custom-log-filters/ with further possibilities discussed here: http://ritt.md/eut

Answer (score 0):

If you have usage tracking configured, which I highly recommend you have, then you can look at when they last did a query. It' not exactly what you are asking for as a user conceivably could login and just sit doing nothing at the entry page. Since the default entry page does not do any reports it does not generate any usage tracking log entries it is possible to login and not do any queries, but as soon as they actually use the solution they will generate a usage tracking entry. Opening a dashboard, report or making a new analysis will create usage tracking entries.

This solution would not give you the exact logout time as a user might be staring at a report for a while after having opened it and before logging out or closing the report down.

I believe that usage tracking is a very cheap approximation of what you want. Most solution will already have usage tracking implemented so all you need to do is create a report looking at max query time for each user. Depending on why you need this that might be enough.

If you want to know how long a user was logged on that is more difficult with this solution, as you would have to group query times together and make an assumption of what constitute a continues use and what is a new logon.